# Hex to pem file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, pem

I have .hex file, how could I get a normal .pem file from it using python? I was trying `binascii.unhexlify()` but it breaks entire structure and doesn't give me what I need. Couldn't find any alternative. Thank you for any help.

Comment: A hex file just indicates that the contents are encoded in hexadecimals. It does not indicate **what is encoded by the hexadecimals**. PEM requires this information in the header / footer. One way to find out what is in the hex file is to convert it to binary and then run the `file` command on it (generally found in Unix distributions / POSIX systems). Hex is also commonly but mistakenly used for binary files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to add comments. Here is a relevant stackoverflow question that might help you with the conversion:

[How to convert private key that is in hex format to private key in pem and/or der format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401343/how-to-convert-private-key-that-is-in-hex-format-to-private-key-in-pem-and-or-de)

You can do the conversion with:

```
import binascii
binascii.unhexlify(hex_data)
binascii.a2b_base64(binascii.unhexlify(hex_data))
```

Comment: That still doesn't give you a .PEM, you'd need a header and footer. You've parroted an incorrect answer, instead of closing the question as a dupe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I mentioned I was trying that and it doesn't give me structure I want. But thank you anyways